# Lenovo 500S-14ISK Linux compatibility

Tags: laptop, lenovo

I would like to buy a [Lenovo 500S-14ISK](https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/notebooks/lenovo+500s+14isk+80q30069ge+ultrabook+silber), but I can't find any reviews on it regarding linux compatibility. Ubuntu does not seem to have certified this laptop (yet)?

Anybody had experience with this model? Since it's a lenovo, my gut says it will work with Ubuntu/Mint out of the box, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: I had a painfull experience with Lenovo. If you want to use virtual-box ask if you can enable virtualization in BIOS.  For some reason it was locked in my BIOS and I had to update the bios. I also have problems with graphics (bad display quality), but I have AMD graphics and you have Intel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I have this model and I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. Most things work fine except there are some minor issues with using the hotkeys (not all of them will work properly).

Comment: I want to buy this laptop too, can you be more specific, what the hotkeys that doesnt workm ? do you recommend this product when using ubuntu?